# Can I get Google maps to ignore part of a search?

Tags: google-maps

I have a website which shows scheduled upcoming bike rides using Google Calendar. The location field automatically links to Google maps, but some of the information can make the Google maps search fail, and there's no way to turn off the map link.

Example: The upcoming ride has in the location field "Seven Hills Station, North side of the train tracks, 9am sharp". When you click on the map link, it just brings up a map of the US. If you search for "Seven Hills Station", it comes up with the train station in Seven Hills NSW, which is what we want. So if there was an operator that made the Google maps search ignore everything after "Hills" (like the question mark in URLs), I could keep displaying the calendar events in the same format and have working maps linked from it. Does anyone know of an operator that can make Google maps ignore part of a search?

Cheers,
Aston

Comment: There is no "guessWhatIWant"-operator. Parse the address on your own and strip what you don't need

Comment: This doesn't sound easy.  Maybe this: after searching and getting a result, you could make a string search; to see if search terms have been ignored.  Then you could trigger a new search without the ignored terms.  Not sure if it could really work.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't need to be dynamic Molle, it's just that if I remove the information about what side of the train line to meet on, people on the website won't know what side of the train line to meet on, so I want to tell Google maps to ignore it, like comment it out or something. "Seven Hills Station // North side of the train tracks" is just as meaningful to human beings as "Seven Hills Station, North side of the train tracks".

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use regex to delete everything after the `,`

using the replace function, this is how you replace something in JS: `str.replace(/,.*/g, "");`

http://jsfiddle.net/gvzpe9h9/